# How do reimplement this Python XML-parsing function in Haskell?

Tags: python, xml, haskell

I recently wrote the following Python function which will take a Google Picasa contacts.xml file and output a dictionary with ID and Name.

```
def read_contacts_file(fn):
    import xml.etree.ElementTree
    x = xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree(file=fn)
    q = [(u.attrib["id"], u.attrib["name"]) for u in x.iter("contact")]
    return dict(q)
```

What this function does is return a dictionary (hashtable, map) with the ID being the key and the Name being the value.

The file itself has the form:

```
<contacts>
 <contact id="f5fdaaee2e80fa01" name="Person A" display="A"/>
 <contact id="8d5256298fd43877" name="Person B" display="B"/>
</contacts>
```

What's the simplest way I can implement this in Haskell?

---

Just wanted to let you know that with everyone's help, I've managed to come up with the following which makes sense to me. Thanks.

```
parseContactsData = M.fromList . runLA (xread >>> f) 
    where f = 
        getChildren 
        >>> hasName "contact" 
        >>> getAttrValue "id" &&& getAttrValue "name"
```

Comment: It would help to have a description of what you want this function to do; not everyone who can help with the Haskell solution will want to figure out what this Python code is doing.

Comment: It would help other people with a similar problem (or lack of knowledge) if you showed which modules you imported, in your new code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example doing it with HXT

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Map

idAssocs = hasName "contact" >>> getAttrValue "id" &&& getAttrValue "name"
dict = fromList `fmap` runX (readDocument [] "contacts.xml" >>> deep idAssocs)
```

Comment: I understand this makes use of arrows. But this syntax just looks really, really complicated compared to my Python version.

Comment: @Snoqual The `>>>` syntax is forward pipelining, while `&&&` applies the two arrows to the same input and produces a pair of their results.  The primary mental contortion is to think of the pipeline structure of parsing/transformation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a minimal example doing the same thing with [tagsoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tagsoup/0.12.2/doc/html/Text-HTML-TagSoup.html):

```
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

assocLookup k dict = [v | (k', v) <- dict, k == k']
readContactsFile fn = fmap parse (readFile fn)

parse contents = do
    TagOpen "contact" attrs <- parseTags contents
    id <- assocLookup "id" attrs
    name <- assocLookup "name" attrs
    return (id, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use the HXT library. Here are some useful information which will get you started: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Conversion_of_Haskell_data_from/to_XML

Particularly useful for you would probably be looking at [3.5 A simple application](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Conversion_of_Haskell_data_from/to_XML#A_simple_application)